# Copy column value to another google spreadsheet file without overwriting

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have the following scenario.
Some columns from formula spreadsheets should be copied sequentially without overwriting the old content into a master spreadsheet file.

I managed to combine the following script

```
function copy() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(),
    target =ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2'),   //fill in the name of the sheet
    lastColumn = target.getLastColumn(),
    sourceVal = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange("C1:C58")
        .getValues();
target.getRange(1, lastColumn + 1, sourceVal.length, sourceVal[0].length)
    .setValues(sourceVal);

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(),
    target =ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2'),   //fill in the name of the sheet
    lastColumn = target.getLastColumn(),
    sourceVal = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange("H1:H58")
        .getValues();
target.getRange(1, lastColumn + 1, sourceVal.length, sourceVal[0].length)
    .setValues(sourceVal);
}
```

This will work for the required amount of columns and it will not overwrite the old information.

Unfortunately, I can not understand how to make this work with other spreadsheet files.

The end result should read from 10 files, 2 columns each file (the columns are not sequential) into a final master file.

Thanks in advance for taking your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
function copy() {
  var sources = [
    {id: '1XTdXQjcy48D63Yl-fHFOvCocZo5jWN10d_fYfhf5umo', // ID of first source file
     sheet1: 'Sheet1',
     range1: 'C1:C58',
     sheet2: 'Sheet1',
     range2: 'H1:H58'
    },
    {id: '12wpXOlkKI2Zb8n5op4xuWQrWn7fyiH8j49NV8kB2b9s',
     sheet1: 'Sheet1',
     range1: 'C1:C58',
     sheet2: 'Sheet1',
     range2: 'H1:H58'
    } // add next sheets
   ]
  sources.forEach(function(val) {
    val.val1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(val.id).getSheetByName(val.sheet1).getRange(val.range1).getValues();
    val.val2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(val.id).getSheetByName(val.sheet2).getRange(val.range2).getValues();
    return val
  })

  var target = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet2')

  for (var i=0; i<sources.length; i++) {
    var lastColumn = target.getLastColumn()
    target.getRange(1, lastColumn + 1, sources[i].val1.length, sources[i].val1[0].length).setValues(sources[i].val1);

    var lastColumn = target.getLastColumn()
    target.getRange(1, lastColumn + 1, sources[i].val2.length, sources[i].val2[0].length).setValues(sources[i].val2);
  }
}
```

Remember about changing IDs[[1]](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openById(String)) of spreadsheets, names of sheets and ranges.

Comment: That is just brilliant. 
I understand it (somehow) and i`m able to change according to the requirements.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try using openById(id):

> - Opens the spreadsheet with the given ID.

Code sample:

```
 // The code below opens a spreadsheet using its ID and logs the name for it.
 // Note that the spreadsheet is NOT physically opened on the client side.
 // It is opened on the server only (for modification by the script).
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("abc1234567");
 Logger.log(ss.getName());
```

For you to access different sheets and insert it to the master file use `openById(id)`.

Hope this helps.